# firebase functions and web pack issues

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use cloud functions for firebase in a react project, so I had installed Google cloud SDK, when running **npm run** the server run without any problems, but webpack is keeping showing me this error :

```js
WARNING in ./~/ajv/dist/ajv.bundle.js
Critical dependencies:
1:476-483 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original
 source to get better results.
 @ ./~/ajv/dist/ajv.bundle.js 1:476-483

ERROR in ./~/translate-api/src/api.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'google-translate-token' in /media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/nod
e_modules/translate-api/src
 @ ./~/translate-api/src/api.js 6:14-47
 ERROR in ./~/cheerio/package.json
Module parse failed: /media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/node_modules/cheerio/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:
966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)

    at Object.parse (/media/azeddine/ducuments/journey/mini apps/Hire-me/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
 @ ./~/cheerio/index.js 11:18-43
```

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
export default {
   entry:[
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
     path.resolve(__dirname,"src")+"/public/script/app.js",
   ],
   output:{
     filename:"bundle.js",
     path:path.resolve(__dirname,"src")+"/dist",
     publicPath: '/',
     debug: true,
   },
   plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
   module:{
     loaders:[
       {
         test:/\.js$/,
         loaders:["react-hot","babel"],
        // exclude:/(node_module)/,
         include:path.resolve(__dirname,"src"),
       },
       {
         test:/\.(css|scss)$/,
         loader:"style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader",
       },
       {
         test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|jpeg|otf)$/,
         loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
        },
     ],
},
resolve: {
   extentions: [ '', '.js' ]
 },
 node:{
   net:"empty",
   dns: "empty" ,
 }
}
```

```js
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original ='hellow world ! from firebase cloud functiondlou';
  // Push it into the Realtime Database then send a response
  admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
    // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
  });
});
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
```